# Google Play - Privacy Policy

Tags: android, privacy-policy

Google Play has notified me to publish a Privacy Policy for my app. I have created a website to host this information. I am planning to update the website link from the developer console shortly.

As per the new policy, Google is asking that we should also update our app to have a link to the privacy policy. Unfortunately I cannot do this anymore as I lost my keystore in a hard-disk crash. Is this step optional? Will Google Play allow my app to be listed with just a privacy policy website link in the Store listing, without the app itself not having the privacy policy details?

Thanks
Balaji

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Google Play's app policy and not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) You absolutely need your privacy policy on the Play Store page PLUS within the app**

This is what Google says:

> If your app requests user data or makes sensitive permissions requests
>   such as Phone, Accounts, Contacts, Camera, or Microphone, you'll need
>   to add a **valid privacy policy** in **two places: your app's Store Listing
>   page (instructions below) and within your app**.

I'd also like to add some more insight why that is the case. If you are into privacy law theory, then I suggest you read [this pdf](http://ec.europa.eu/justice/data-protection/article-29/documentation/opinion-recommendation/files/2013/wp202_en.pdf) by a Pan-European privacy body, otherwise I just suggest to [read the summary here](http://www.iubenda.com/blog/privacy-policy-app-store-guide-link/):

> The essential scope of information about data processing 1) must be
>   available to the users before app installation, via the app store.
>   Secondly, the relevant information about the data processing 2) must
>   also be accessible from within the app, after installation.

You can see - in theory - this is absolutely requested and required and you should strive to get that done. Hope this helps. p.s. I work for a startup that helps with privacy policies. [(link)](http://iubenda.com/mobile)

Comment: Thank you very much Simon. Guess I will have to host a new app and unpublish the current one, as I cannot update it anymore. Will check out your link.